# C# SQL Server Add Roles to Database User

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I have created the following code below for programatically adding a login and user to SQL Server 2016 from C# code. I also need to assign the new user the relevant roles for Read & Write access to the database, BUT I cannot find any examples that helps me when using the cmdText string below.

I'm assuming the roles I need to add to this new user are:

```
db_datareader
db_datawriter
```

This newly created user needs to have access to just one database and be able to add/edit/delete/update records from existing database tables.

I only need to add this new login/user just once. Once I've figured this out, I then just need two more actions:

Write a method with `cmdText` that will allow me to do the following:

- Update the password for this user "admin"
- Delete the "admin" user account at a later stage.

Code:

```
 static readonly string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConnection"].ConnectionString;

 public static void CreateSqlServerUserAccount()
 {
        string usertobeadded = "admin";
        string password = "ComplexPasswordExample123456";
        string databasename = "DatabaseNameHere";

        string cmdText = "CREATE LOGIN " + usertobeadded + " WITH PASSWORD = '" +
        password + "';  USE " + databasename + "; CREATE USER " + usertobeadded + " FOR LOGIN " + usertobeadded + ";";

        // The connection is automatically closed at the end of the using block.
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, connection);
                connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                log.Info("NEW Login & User Account created on Microsoft SQL Server");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error("Error creating a new login and user account on Microsoft SQL Server: ", ex);
                SystemEvents.DatabaseExceptions(ex);
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

...allow me to do the following:

1) Update the password for this user "admin"

```
ALTER LOGIN admin WITH PASSWORD = 'newpassword' OLD_PASSWORD = 'oldpassword'
```

2) Delete the "admin" user account.

```
DROP USER [ IF EXISTS ] admin
```

Comment: Thank you so much, will try this. For the first task in my above wish list, it seems that I will need to create a new role, then add permissions to this role, then add the role to the user "admin" in order to complete the exercise. If you have any ideas would be greatly appreciated. I'm currently reviewing the Microsoft help guide, but not finding it very intuitive.

Comment: ```1) CREATE ROLE <MyNewRole>2) GRANT SELECT ON <OBJECT> TO <MyNewRole> 3) exec sp_addrolemember @rolename = <MyNewRole>, @membername = 'admin'

Comment: I found that adding the Login account to the server role sysadmin would give the required access to the server, but my understanding is this is not the most secure way to do this as the same account has lots of other features sets that they wont and shouldnt need.